# Android/Java Decryption Block Size Calculation - Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am getting an error "Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH" and I am not sure why.  Can someone please tell me how to fix this?

Here is how I call it

```
String encrypted = "E5ADDEB05D9D7B3925B7DE16B560D87C";
String sKey = "3985661DD71D591665BD39476636486B";
```

This is the procedure

```
public static String decrypt2(final String sEncryptedMessageBase64,
                              final String sSymKeyHex,
                              final String sIvHex)
{
    final byte[] byteEncryptedMessage = Base64.decode(sEncryptedMessageBase64, Base64.DEFAULT);

    try
    {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        final SecretKeySpec symKey = new SecretKeySpec(byteSymKeyData, "AES");
        final IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(byteIvData);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, symKey, iv);
        final byte[] encodedMessage = cipher.doFinal(byteEncryptedMessage);
        final String message = new String(encodedMessage, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        return message;
    }
    catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {

        Log.e("%%%%%", e.getMessage());

        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Unexpected exception during decryption", e);
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting

```
error:1e06b07b:Cipher functions:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH
```

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: You're creating an empty array encryptedMessage with proper size but you don't copy any data into it.

Comment: You are right, I have updated the code above but it still gives the same error

Comment: How are you encrypting your data?

Comment: Why are you base64 decoding what looks like hex data?

Comment: I updated the code to include the C++ encryption (java will be decrypting it).  Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: The encryption code doesn't base64 encode either so it's not clear why you've called the parameter that and why you're trying to base64 decode hex data.

Comment: I am updating some existing code (please ignore the variable name but I will fix it)  How should I fix it?  What should it be?  without the Base64.decode it tells me expected IV length of 16 but was 24

Comment: i thought HexEncoder() did encode it to base 64....https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexEncoder

Comment: it says 'hex' and base 16 right in the docs so I'm not sure why you thought that, besides, the sample data you are passing in is clearly hex. You need to hex decode everything you're passing in. Please fix the code, if you are getting any errors, show the precise error, stack trace, etc. More generally, you're better off just using TLS or libsodium instead of reinventing encryption from primitives badly.